# How to have different file links to an Eclipse project (not importing it)?

Tags: eclipse, svn, deployment

I noticed when I import a file, the file is copied to the work space, but can I just create a file link in a Eclipse project? So when I modify the files in Eclipse, the files in the linked location is modified. In this way, I can version control the files using SVN. And I don't need to copy the modified files back to its dedicated directory when deployment.

The following is a more detailed description of my problem:

I have a cgi application located and runs in apache. The app runs with diff configuration files for different 'projects' which is more like showing different dataset with its corresponding configuration file. My task is to write the configurations files which will require some perl callback functions, css files and images. All these files have their own dedicated directories located in different places in the company server which i have not much control with.. So far, I just use command line to modify files and keeping old copies for version control. If I can do something like my above description, I will be able to have a central place to work on and do SVN. Or do you have a better idea how I should set up my work environment?

Thanks heaps in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to conveniently to version control files from different places and can deploy them to the correct directories after modified. It's .......  using..... the ANT build file... I just have all files imported to a single project and use an ANT build to distribute them back to their corresponding destination.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

File -> New File -> Advanced (at the bottom) -> Link to file in the file system

Manu

Comment: Hi Manuel, I can't see the 'Advanced' in 'New File'. There is only File->New->Others. Then inside 'Others', I can't find any type with the name link.. Maybe we are talking about a different Eclipse version. I am using Eclipse Galileo Packages. Any idea for my Eclipse version?

Comment: Oh.. i get it now... the 'Advanced' button is hidden after I selected the file type, then in the 'File name' inputting page. Thanks heaps! That save me a lot of brain cells in remembering all different locations.

Comment: Hmhmhm... i just had a test... it seems SVN (using Subclipse) is NOT version controlling the linked file, not only checking in the .project file which remembers the link of the file. Hmhm.. that's not really meeting my requirement.. Do u have any other ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `svn:external` http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

One drawback though, you have to update your other projects once you commit a shared files.

Comment: Thanks for your extra information on this foreseen issue. I will keep that in mind.